# C# Selenium CSS-selector attribute not working

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to run Selenium test, where it waits until a certain attribute has a value to continue and when checking in the browser (Code inspection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), it locates the element using the css locator, but I in when running the test, I always get a timeout - and the element gets the desired value before that time

1. Checked that the css locator is valid in "inspect code" and search
2. Tried easier locators - it locates the id, but can't locate the attribute and its value
3. Googling like crazy to find the solution

**My code (CMExtensionMethods.IsElementVisible == ExpectedConditions, does the same thing):**

```
public static WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
waitForElement.Until(CMExtensionMethods.IsElementVisible(By.CssSelector("#page_progress[style~='display:']")));


public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> IsElementVisible(By identifier) {
           return (driver) =>
           {
               try {
                   return IfElementVisible(driver.FindElement(identifier));
               }
               catch(NoSuchElementException) {
                   return null;
               }
           };
       }
       // Part of the method above
       private static IWebElement IfElementVisible(IWebElement element) {
           return element.Displayed ? element : null;
       }
```

**HTML code on the page(page_progress style changes depending on the website state - the style is either like this or empty):**

```
    <div id="page_progress" class="loading-progress" style="display: none;"> 
    </div>
    <div id="page_saveindicator" class="unsaved-changes" style="display: 
     none;"></div>
```

**Expectation:** The code to continue right after the style gets a value

**Result:** Nothing is located and I get a timeout error after 5 sec (as set), despite the element having the attribute and the value it's supposed to

Might be worth mentioning - the method *IsElementVisible* works - tested on IDs, and CSSselectors using Class and Id (alone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) include `style=display:...` in your locator to determine visibility. Selenium does that for you when you use `.Displayed` or use `ExpectedConditions` and wait for visible. Just locate the element normally, e.g. both of your elements have an ID so use `By.Id("page_progress")`, like

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("page_progress"));
```

and Selenium will take care of the rest.

Comment: Haven't thought of that, I'll have to give it a try as soon as I get back to my code and I'll post the result

Comment: This has solved it for me...I somehow expected that "Visible" means in the page, even if not displayed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The wrong comparison operator is being used in the CSS selector.

The `~=` operator must exactly match the value of the attribute.

Either add the `block` part of the attribute value, or change the comparison operator to `^=`.

```
By.CssSelector("#page_progress[style^='display:']")
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: According to W3School, the `~=` is not for the exact value and nothing else, but for everything that contains the value. And as I mentioned, it does work in the browser, so there shouldn't be a difference in Selenium, right?


https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp